# ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (3,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, lsa

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9],
               [10, 11, 12]])
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(A)
print (np.dot(u, np.dot(np.diag(s), vt)))
```

I use numpy for creating the matrix and It shows script error below.

> ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (3,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Comment: What does this have o do with `lsa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `print(u.shape, s.shape, vt.shape)` after the SVD, you'll see that `u` is a 4x4 matrix, whereas `np.dot(np.diag(s), vt)` returns a 3x3 matrix.  Hence why the dot product with `u` cannot be computed.  Setting the `full_matrices` option of `np.linalg.svd` to `False` will return a 4x3 matrix, and allow the dot product to be computed.  I.e.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], 
               [4, 5, 6], 
               [7, 8, 9],
               [10, 11, 12]])
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
print(np.dot(u, np.dot(np.diag(s), vt)))
```

Whether that is the right thing to do for your specific problem is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a dot product between two incompatible matrices. The number of the columns of `u` (it has the shape of (4x4)) isn't equal to the number of rows of `np.dot(np.diag(s), vt)` (it has the shape of (3x3))